# How/if to use android.provider.CallLog.Calls.LIMIT_PARAM_KEY

Tags: android, calllog

I ran into this const [android.provider.CallLog.Calls.LIMIT_PARAM_KEY][1].

It is for some reason greyed out in the documentation, and when I try to use it, the app crashes (sqlite error)

Does anyone know how to use this? (if we at all should use it)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a Uri.Builder and append the query parameter:

```
    Uri limitedCallLogUri = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(CallLog.Calls.LIMIT_PARAM_KEY, "50").build();
```

will limit the response to 50.

Comment: I am using what you suggest, but it still gives out all the calls

Comment: @hungson175 Can't confirm. Seems to work fine. On which device and Android version? Maybe you can report about this, as this is the exact same thing Google said developers should use: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175198972#comment6